# Why isn't my insert trigger firing?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Here is the trigger that I created, when I check to see if the table "raw_agent_data_buffer" has any rows / data its empty, even after the "table raw_agent_data" received more data / inserts.

Any idea why?

```
USE [agents]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[raw_insert]
ON [dbo].[raw_agent_data]
after INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO agents.dbo.raw_agent_data
      SELECT i.post_id,
             i.post_name,
             i.post_data
      FROM   inserted i
  END

GO
```

Comment: Is this a valid insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the text in your question you are expecting rows to be added to a table called `raw_agent_data_buffer`.

Your trigger doesn't add any rows to a table of that name.

It inserts to a different table `agents.dbo.raw_agent_data` so it should be clear why you aren't seeing rows added to `raw_agent_data_buffer`

Comment: You are totally correct. That was the issue (luckily it only affected 19 rows that I am fixing now).